# Android studio automatically open's documentation view

Tags: android-studio

I don't know if it is bug or kind of setting, but it is very annoying while typing value i.e.   `android:layout_gravity=""`, it opens hints with dropdown, and after a while the documentation view gets opened and hides the dropdown with hints.

[image]

I checked that no button is suspended or anything like that. I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Strange, because I've not changed anything with AS from months and there was no such behavior before. There's solution:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's annoying!

Comment: This doesn't work for me on 2.2. So annoying. 
Hope someone will come up with a new solution.

Comment: @uval, did you try to restart Android Studio after changes had been applied?
At worst, you can go to:                      
[File] -> [Invalidate Caches / Restart...]

Comment: @Andrey-WD thanks. I didn't try that. Anyway, I'm using 2.3 now on a new Ubuntu release, and I don't have this problem anymore.

Comment: I think most of us changed this behavior unconsciously. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55670179/1797950)  to set to popup behavior

Answer (score 24):

Follow the simple steps to remove open `Documentation` by cursor move :

> Android Studio -> File -> Setting -> Editor -> General

Right side of the screen go to Others :

- **Uncheck** `checkBox` **show quick documentation of mouse move** & **Apply**.

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Preferences > Editor > General > CodeCompletion > uncheck Auto popup feature

Answer (score 11):

I found out that I don't want to disable the documentation. 
Instead, I set the window to be 'Opened as Popup',

[image]

This displays the documentation aside to the cursor and autocloses it automatically.

[image]

Surely I've set it before as a 'Tool Window' to see the full content and then I forgot to set it back.

Answer (score 9):

Note that this functionality has been moved recently. It's now in:

> Android Studio -> Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Other.

Uncheck "quick documentation on mouse move".

Answer (score 7):

Studio 3.4.2, somehow had setting checked, uncheck it.

File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion.
[image: studio-doc-autopopup]
Cheers

Answer (score 5):

[image: Please check image.]
This the only correct answer as far i know because i sorted out this way only. Just click on Help>find Action>auto(in the search box)> and uncheck the checkbox in the image shown

Comment: This is exactly the same as what the accepted answer already suggests without adding any information.

Comment: the advice given doesn't even match the screenshot provided. just go `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Completion` and un-check `Auto-display documentation in x ms`

Answer (score 5):

For Android Studio 4.x ~ Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1

Preferences > Editor > Code Editing > Quick Documentation > Show quick documentation on mouse move: **unchecked**

[image: screenshot]