# Android Studio Turn Off Documentation Popup

Tags: android-studio-2.2

I've been fighting this for a while now.  It's gotten really irritating.
I've tried turning off

- File->Settings->Editor->General->show quick documentation on mouse move

  File->Settings->Editor->CodeCompletion->autopopup code completion

  File->Settings->Editor->ParameterInfo->autopopup in (ms)

  Dragging the documentation window to the side.

And none of these have worked.  I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 on Ubuntu Linux.  What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387940/android-studio-automatically-opens-documentation-view?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: This is such an annoying "feature".  Why does JetBrains enable all these distractions without permission? Constant auto popups that interfere with programming flow.  No wonder VSCode is taking over.

Answer (score 8):

This option

File->Settings->Editor->General->Other->uncheck "Show quick documentation on mouse move"
worked for me on Android Studio 3.0.1

Regards!

Comment: Mine was unchecked and I am getting these pop ups.

Answer (score 6):

Android Studio -> Preference -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion -> Show the documentation pupup in XX ms

uncheck the option.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works.  Seems like you get the popups whether you want them or not.  Thank you google for the update!

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the pop up comes out, just click on the hamburger menu button, there you will see the options you have. Here is an image for you guys:

[image: Here you see the simple steps]

Comment: I'll be damned, something finally works!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The location in Settings for turning this feature off has been moved.

New Location: Preferences > Editor > Code Editing > Quick Documentation

[image]